# Add jQuery error handling to all images on JSF pages inside lists, grids

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

To start, a little background. What I am trying to accomplish is a client-side error handler for my JSF application for images that does *something* anytime an image fails to load. The something is a little complicated so I will pick an easy example that does something similar in that it rewrites the src attribute to a different image. Also, my images are stored on Amazon S3, so image requests are not passed through the filters in my JSF application, and I would like to keep it that way.

Effectively I want to do this for ALL images application wide (with a few embellishments):

```
$('img').error(function() {
  var newImage = 'somethingbasedofftheoriginalurl.jpg'; //pseudocode
  $(this).attr('src','newImage');
}
```

The problem I am having with this is that it does not work for dynamic lists or grids such as a Primefaces DataGrid. It will add the error handler for images on the first page, but does not do so for subsequent pages when using the paginator. It obviously only attaches the handler to elements that existed when `$('img')` was called.

To the point:

Is there a way to attach a client-side universal error handler for ALL images application-wide in my JSF application? It doesn't have to be jQuery specifically, but having it client-side is requisite, up to the point where everyone tells me it isn't possible... Also, having this code in as few places as possible is important as well. I can't be adding it to every blasted xhtml page in my entire application.

Comment: have you try using .on("error", funtion(){});

Comment: @Juan: doesn't work for `error` because it won't bubble up to `$(document)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PrimeFaces paginates using ajax. So all you basically need to do is to re-execute that script on complete of PrimeFaces ajax response, which is observable by the custom event `pfAjaxComplete`.

So, all in all, this should do:

```
$(document).on("pfAjaxComplete", function(event, xhr, options) {
    // Do the job here.
});
```

Comment: Works in all the cases I have tried thus far. Thanks, you're a life saver.